# Parsing oauth client token in node js

Tags: node.js, json, unicode

I am running into unicode conversion issues with node js for my oauth client id. There is no particular structure in my provided client id and so I don't want to use hacks around string parsing. I tried `he.decode` and `unidecode` npm packages but with no success.

**Input:**
`‌eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzpqrxYZBwIn0\\u003d`

**Expected after conversion:**
`‌eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzpqrxYZBwIn0\=`

**My Testing:**

```
>he.decode("eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0\\u003d")
>'eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0\\u003d'
>unidecode("eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0\\u003d")
>'eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0\\u003d'
```

Since the client ID is provided by the site for my app I have no way of removing that additional `\`.

Comment: Looks like the first \ escapes the other \ so the unicode character becomes unparseable

Comment: Yes, that's right. How do I unescape it and be prudent not to remove any intentional \ in my client id?

Comment: Are you sure you want the ending to be \= and not =

Comment: I tried and was able to authenticate using both. So \= or = any is good.

Comment: I'm that case I will post an answer in a few minutes. I have with success used the NPM library "unraw"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the unraw package https://www.npmjs.com/package/unraw

This is the output i get when using `decoudeURI` vs `unraw`

```
const unraw = require("unraw");

let token = "eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0\\u003d";
let unraw_token = unraw.unraw(token)
console.log(token)
console.log(decodeURI(token))
console.log(unraw_token)
```

output:

```
> eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0\u003d

> eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0\u003d

> eyJob3N0S2V5IjoiYzBjYzQyOTYtMWU0Ny0zNjA4LWFiMDAtM2E5ODllZDE3MWNmIiwiYWRkb25LZXkiOiJwcm9kdWN0aXYtZGV2LWF0bGFzc2lhbi1qaXJhLWNvbm5lY3QtYXBwIn0=
```